# Set API Key when doing reqests.get in Python

Tags: python, api, request

Im trying to get data from one api, and I have key for it, but Im always getting an `401 error` and when I print it `{"error":"API key required."}`.
What am I doing wrong?

I have tried these 5 things, and error is always the same:

```
import json
import requests


api_url = "https://idir.uta.edu/claimbuster/api/v2/score/text/Denver%20lost%20to%20LA%20Lakers"

response =  requests.get(api_url, headers = {'Authorization': 'Token xxx'})
#response =  requests.get(api_url, headers = {'Authorization': 'xxx'})
#response =  requests.get(api_url, headers = {'Auth': 'Token xxx'})
#response =  requests.get(api_url, headers = {'Auth': 'xxx'})
#response =  requests.get(api_url,key ='xxx')
#response =  requests.get(api_url, headers = {'x-api-key': 'Token xxx'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://idir.uta.edu/claimbuster/api/docs/) says it should be

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'x-api-key': 'Token xxx',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': '',
    'Accept-Language': '*',
}

response =  requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: try testing the key here https://idir.uta.edu/claimbuster/api/docs/ by entering the API key, and some text. After clicking the `/api/v2/score/text/<input_text>` dropdown

Comment: it works there, but it does not work when I want to add api url in my code

Comment: I edited it, try using those headers. And replace `'x-api-key': 'Token xxx',` with your token ofcourse

Comment: Yeah, the word token shouldn't be there